# How to connect commits from Terminal on Mac with activity log on Github page?

Tags: git, github, terminal, account

I created a repo on GitHub and used Terminal on Mac to commit and push a project.
Everything works fine, but on [my GitHub page](https://github.com/bohdandrahan/Genome-diversity-model-Seed-Root/commits/master) it seems like commits were made not from my github account but some guest account (I assume it used my Mac os name but I could be wrong).
Consequently my activity log on GitHub page does not register any commits that I make.
How can I fix it?

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/why-are-my-commits-linked-to-the-wrong-user/

Comment: https://github.community/t5/Support-Protips/Why-is-my-commit-associated-with-the-wrong-person/ba-p/6728

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add your user name and email to global configs of git locally for your user name to be associated with commits.

you can do it as follows:

```
git config --global user.name "example-user-name"
git config --global user.email "example@user.com"
```

after setting your user name to global configs, make some minor changes to code, maybe add a space and try committing and pushing. your username should appear :)